# An identity for random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

My professor gave me the following identity for random variables in her office hours, and I cannot find reference to it anywhere whatsoever.

Given a random variable $X_n$ and an estimator $X'_n$,

$X'_n = \frac{n-1}{n}X'_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}X_n$.

Can anybody tell me if they have seem this identity before or something like it and whether or not it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple filter.  It is auto-regressive moving average, (ARMA), weighted towards the more recent values.  It reduces the noise, so that trends can be seen more easily.
Filters are an important part of signal processing.  A famous one is the Kalman filter.  For example, they are why digital TV channels can be packed more closely than analogue TV channels.
The idea is that the signal changes slowly, but noise changes from one sample to the next.  The averaging reinforces the signal, but reduces the variance of the noise.
This filter, (X'=(n-1)X'/n+X/n), needs room to store one value.  A similar filter, that just takes the actual average of the $n$ most recent samples, needs room to store $n-1$ previous samples.
Other filters can be designed to exclude signals from neighbouring channels.   So then if the signal is $\sin 0.24t$, you get a large output $X'$, but if the signal is $\sin 0.23t$ or $\sin 0.25t$, you get a small output $X'$.